# groovy dsl - is infix operator possible?

Tags: groovy, dsl

Is it possible to create a dsl with infix operators in Groovy ?

I've researched the builder pattern, invokeMethod, propertyInvoke and the MetaClass and I can only see how to use it to create tree structures using prefix operators (polish notation). What I want to do is build tree structures with infix operators that have binding precedence rules.

eg: if this pseudo code evaluates to 8:

```
add(2,multiply(3, 2))
```

I want to express it as:

```
2 add 3 multiply 2
```

where multiply binds more tightly than add. I'm using arithmetic just as an example - my application is something quite different.

I don't want to write and support my own parser so I'm hoping groovy has a mechanism for this ???

EDIT: While searching for solutions I've found this is possible and well documented in Scala  (see chapter 33: Combinator Parsers in Programming in Scala by Martin Odersky).

Comment: it strictly has to follow that `2 add 3 multiply 2` syntax? Could it be `2.add 3 multiply 2`?

Comment: if it were `2 add 3 multiply 2 subtract 4` it should be understood as `add(2, subtract(multiply(3, 2), 4)`?

Comment: Yes exactly - just the normal order of operation for arithmetic.

Comment: To give a bit more context, the operators return expressions to be evaluated, this way we can build a syntax tree which can be evaluated recursively. In this example the expressions evaluate to numbers: 2 + 3 * 2 - 4 = 2 + 6 - 4 = 8 - 4 = 4

Comment: I see. Can the dot be added?

Comment: I can live with the dot if there is a way to make it work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49746/discussion-between-user1373164-and-will-p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you found an answer in Scala, but anyway, in Groovy, although it needs the dot (or an AST to insert it automatically), it's not hard to do the command tree:

**UPDATE**: added a `floatNode` method, whose precedence is based in the `precedence` list. The nodes with higher precedence "float" upward:

```
class Operation {

  static final precedence = ['minus', 'add', 'multiply', 'divide']

  def left, right, method
  Operation parent

  def invokeMethod(String method, args) {
    def o = new Operation(
      parent: this, left: right, method: method, right: args[0])

    this.floatNode(o)
  }

  def floatNode(Operation op) {
    if (op.hasHigherPrecedenceThan(this)) {
      op.parent = this.parent
      this.parent = op
      if (op.parent) { this.parent = op.parent.floatNode(op) }
      return this
    }
    else {
      return op
    }
  }

  def hasHigherPrecedenceThan(Operation o) {
    return precedence.indexOf(this.method) > precedence.indexOf(o.method)
  }

  String toString() { "Operation($left $method $right, parent=$parent)" }
}
```

Tests:

```
Integer.metaClass.invokeMethod = { String method, args ->
  new Operation(parent: null, method: method, left: delegate, right: args.head())
}


a = 2.add 3 multiply 4 minus 5 divide 6 add 7 

println a
```

The `println` will output:

```
Operation(3 minus 5, 
    parent=Operation(5 add 7, 
        parent=Operation(2 add 3, 
            parent=Operation(3 multiply 4, 
                parent=Operation(5 divide 6, parent=null)))))
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but it looks promising and answers my original question. I'm not sure how precedence resolution will work out though (left:this will nest in order encountered right ?), in the example 3 * 4 should be the first thing to evaluate.  But this is a good starting point - thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, `left:this` will nest in order encountered. I think the tree can be traversed to work on operator precedence. Will write on that asap

Comment: i think the dot could be replaced with a function call, something like `let 2 add 3 multiply 4 minus 5`...

Comment: yes, very nice - a bit more like a linked list than a tree but it does  seem to resolve it correctly and it's a nice simple approach. Thanks again for the input.

Comment: You're right. Also, the `left` must be changed to match the operation, and not the value.